# Flutter WillPopScope disable the swipe left to go back in IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, gesture

I use `WillPopScope` in my flutter app and it disable the "Swipe left to go back" that is really usefull in IOS. How to keep the `WillPopScope` but re-add the iOS gesture ?

Comment: Hi, did you found the solution for your issue?

Answer (score 12):

If `onWillPop` is null, the swipe back feature is enabled again.

```dart
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: isLoading ? () async => false : null,
  child: child);
```

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score -3):

If I understand it correctly, you don't want the android user to use the back button, but the ios user may use the swipe left gesture. (because the ios user doesn't have a back button).

In that case, you can make the willpopscope (false or true) a variable.

And within the initstate you can create a function that defines the platform:

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // Android-specific code
  // here you can set the variable to true
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // iOS-specific code
  // here you can set the variable to false

}
```

In case you wan't to disable the back button on the appBar, that's another line of code within the appBar.

Comment: No, I want both to have the WillPopScope because in it, i change the preffered orientation... But If I use WillPopScore, the "swipe to go back" is disabled... I would like a function to re-enable it...

Comment: Ok I understand, I gave another answer

Answer (score -3):

In order to control the behaviour of you willpopscope. You can make the true or false a variable.

```
  onWillPop: () async => false,
```

with a variable that would be:

```
bool myVariable = false;

  onWillPop: () async => myVariable,
```

To change the behaviour you can make a function that uses SetState to change 'myVariable'.